# Show cell selection in Excel when Excel not in focus

Tags: c#, wpf

We have created our own FindAndReplace dialog for Excel. We are using WPF for creating this dialog.

When we give this dialog as modal and when we give find, it was showing the results, when we click the results the selection is happening in excel, but user need to close the dialog then only he can go and edit the selected cells in excel, since this is modal dialog.

I tried out by changing the dialog from modal to modeless, but when we click on the results in our dialog, the cell selection is not happening in excel. But when we click on excel it was showing the selection.

We need to show the selection in excel based on the result we click in our dialog without losing the focus.

I tried out using Range.Select() and Range.Activate(), but still no use.

Please help me in selecting the cell in excel without losing the focus in our dialog.

Comment: Cant say for sure, but from what I understand the issue is that Excel updates after Dialog Window is closed. If that's the case, try to move the Dialog Window to another Thread

Comment: we are using separate thread only for dialog, but still we are not seeing the selection in excel.